# How to show an animated gif as pop up and an alert after some seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have an HTML page and unfortunatly I don't know much about it. In my HTML page there is a simple button that redirect to another website. What I would like to do is to show a popup that advise the user that he is moving to another site. If he accepts so he is redirected, if not then he stays in page.

I've made a graphic for all the process described before and it is a simple gif animated. what I wanna do is this:

The user click on the button 
the gif animated pop up (and all the background is unclickable with a dark color if it's possible to do)
after 2 seconds the alert pop up next to the gif.

I've an example of what I wanna do. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lGhi.jpg

Comment: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Comment: You should check jQueryUI and its modal view: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: Thanks I m going to check it out

Comment: why dont you just bring up a box that fills the page set its opacity to 0.2 or what ever, then put your alert box ontop of that. set pointer events of everything except the alert box to none when the alert box is shown, if it isnt shown enable all pointer events ... saying that, what @kalpeshpatel has linked is perfect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample i created in js fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uoggqrzk/3/)

I use 2 overlapping divs to achieved this, wait 2 seconds and the pop-out will automatically show.

Hope this helps :)

**HTML**

```
    <div id = "pop-out">
    <div id = "message">
        Message goes here
        <button class = "ok"> Ok </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id = "container">
    Content goes here 
    <button>You can't click me</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#pop-out {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}
div#message {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
              $("#pop-out").show();     
       },2000);

    $("button.ok").click(function(){
        $("#pop-out").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Just one question where should I put the GIF

Comment: you can add another div for the gif :) im gonna try to put some gif later. and update this answer :)